# jQuery open external toggle expanded, default is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a toggle slide. Is it possible to achieve the functionality below?

When I open an anchor link (that relies on id), e.g. `http://websitename.com/page#name`, the toggle slides are opened.

However, when I open the link without an anchor name, e.g. `http://websitename.com/page`, 
the toggle is closed.

[Here is my toggle](http://jsfiddle.net/9EFNK/19/)

Many thanks for any advice

Comment: your question is not clear, and can you post your anchor link html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like

```
if(window.location.hash === "#showpanel") {
  $('.showpanel').slideToggle('slow');
}
```

If you changed your div classes to ids, you could probably code something a little more elegantly with

```
$(window.location.hash).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean but is this what you want?

```
if(window.location.hash === "name"){
     $('.showpanel').show();
     $('.showpanel2').show();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9EFNK/21/